# Cakephp Input type radio. How to use Form helper for radio options having some description and paragraph of text.

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to use `Cakephp Form` helper for creating Radio buttons. But I've paragraphs of text and some design for each radio option.

How to Insert these type of radio buttons using `Cakephp Form helper`. I've seen before, after and separator options.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try implementing it `$this->Form->input(array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => array(...)`, see how it looks like, apply css rules to `div.radio input[type="radio"]`, look at the FormHelper code to understand how it works. Then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form helper doesn't do what you need to do, you can either extend it using your own helper or simply create the markup by hand in your form.

Make sure you name your fields correctly otherwise the form post won't be in the correct format for CakePHP to handle.